# Inserting a list of values in place of a value in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace, floating-point

I have a list of values:

```
a = [0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 1.3, 1.5]
```

I would like to replace one of these values with a list of values.

```
b = [1.1, 1.6, 1.8]
```

For example, let us suppose that I want to replace the value 1.3 with the values in list b.
I tried this method but did not get the desired result:

```
new_a = [b if x==1.3 else x for x in a]
```

In this way I insert a list into the list.

```
[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, [1.1, 1.6, 1.8], 1.5]
```

The result I would like to achieve instead is:

```
[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 1.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.5]
```

Comment: It works for me. new_a gives as result `[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, [1.1, 1.6, 1.8], 1.5]` which is consistent with your question

Comment: What is the output your code gives you, and what would you like the output to be? If you could edit your question with this information that would be great, as above your code does what you want, but I guess you want the output to look a bit different

Comment: Looks like you want `[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 1.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.5]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below method gives what you want. I have done this by getting the position of 1.3 in `a` (`idx`), then take the list up to that position, plus `b` plus the list after that position:

```
idx = a.index(1.3)
new_a = a[:idx] + b + a[idx+1:]
```

Output:

```
[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 1.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` method to get the index of the element with value `1.3`; then assign `b` to a slicing of `a` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) regarding the semantics of assignment when the target is a slicing)

```
ix = a.index(1.3)
a[ix : ix + 1] = b

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[0.5, 2.3, 3.1, 1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 1.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.5]
```

**Timings** (for this input; includes setup code -- i.e. defining `a` and `b`).

In case you need to create a new list, the second set of results below are derived from repeatedly executing the same two statements above plus one more statement prior, `c = a.copy()`, which creates a *shallow copy* of `a`.

```
# oda
255 ns ± 4.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
# oda (make a copy of a using a.copy() and assign to c, then modify a as above)
290 ns ± 5.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

# Emi
366 ns ± 8.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
```